# Maven "checksum validation failed, expected xxx but is yyy for" on upload from Jenkins to Artifactory

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

From time to time Jenkins builds with Maven have a checksum validation failure when uploading to Artifactory:

```
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ example-matcher ---
[INFO] Uploading: https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/example/test/examplematcher/example-matcher/183/example-matcher-183.pom
[INFO] Uploaded: https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/example/test/examplematcher/example-matcher/183/example-matcher-183.pom (10 KB at 4.2 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/example/test/examplematcher/example-matcher/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected e57ff3c617c84b922d5806a0ba7a9477b274919b but is f64094cf27d28dce9a8fe3fce63dd9c4d113b22a for https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/example/test/examplematcher/example-matcher/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/example/test/examplematcher/example-matcher/maven-metadata.xml (3 KB at 8.3 KB/sec)
[INFO] Uploading: https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/example/test/examplematcher/example-matcher/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Uploaded: https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/example/test/examplematcher/example-matcher/maven-metadata.xml (3 KB at 6.2 KB/sec)
```

Any idea, why this is happening and how to stop it from happening?

Answer (score 2):

This warning message is due to Artifactory's checksum validation feature. When a file is deployed Artifactory, based on the "Checksum Policy" defined in the local repository, will verify the checksum that was sent from the client to Artifactory and if the checksum is not the same you will receive this warning.

You can read more on the "Checksum Policy" [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Local+Repositories).

Comment: Sure. I know and understand that, however I'm looking for possible causes for that mismatch. Jenkins is the only one writing into Artifactory, there are no concurrent builds. The just by Jenkins uploaded artifact's checksum fails to validate. Some builds are fine, some fail with this error without any pattern, I'm able to identify.

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong, but I'm investigating the same kind of problem, and my reading suggests to me the the warning message is due not to Artifactory complaining about the uploaded file checksum, but rather due to Maven complaining about the downloaded maven-metadata.xml file checksum.

```
[INFO] Downloading: https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/example/test/examplematcher/example-matcher/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected e57ff3c617c84b922d5806a0ba7a9477b274919b but is f64094cf27d28dce9a8fe3fce63dd9c4d113b22a for https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/example/test/examplematcher/example-matcher/maven-metadata.xml
```

(If that's wrong, I'm happy to be corrected.) So I think that partly answers "why this is happening", but I haven't yet figured out "how to stop it from happening".

Comment: Did you ever figure out the cause?

Comment: My notes say "I guess I have no real evidence that this is causing any problems,
even suspected or guessed problems. So that makes this not too urgent."

Comment: OK thanks.  I think in my case it may have been caused by either a connectivity issue or that I was using a too-recent version (the most recent version according ot maven) of one of my artifacts; from possibly faulty memory I think I downgraded the version and it went away.

Comment: When I’ve seen this happen with nexus it is because nexus’ metadata for a snapshot is corrupted and needs to be rebuilt. I don’t know what corrupts it in the first place.